# MIPS is it possible to store a word into a .data variable?

Tags: mips

I am using QtSpim

say I have  this code to get the input:

```
.data
n: .word

.text
.global main

main:
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t0, $v0
```

is it possible to store the value of $t0 into n ?

Comment: should be no reason why not.  what happens when you try it?

Comment: syntax error:  sw n, ($t0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know QtSpim's syntax but the syntax of sw instruction is `sw $t, offset($s)`. So you need to use

```
sw $t0, n($zero)
```

or

```
la $t1, n
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```